# Extract record from array without case sensitivity

Tags: jquery, html

I have a sorted array contains fixed length data. The array is as follow,

```
var samplearray = [12122013Sample1,
                   12122013sam   1.5,
                   10122013sample1

              ];
```

From this array I want to get the records matched to "Sample1". That is, the following records should be returned:

```
12122013Sample1
10122013sample1
```

With out case sensitivity. Is it possible?

Comment: In your `sampleaArray`, do you mean for the items in the array to be strings?  Right now, the data definition you show will just cause an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using plain javascript and assuming you mean for the data in the array to be strings:

```
var samplearray = ["12122013Sample1",
                   "12122013sam   1.5",
                   "10122013sample1"];

var matches = [], re = /sample1/i;
for (var i = 0; i < samplearray.length; i++) {
    if (re.test(samplearray[i])) {
        matches.push(samplearray[i]);
    }
}
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/WvSFz/

Comment: Thank you so much for your valuable reply.. I want to know something based on this function.. In this function you use (re = /sample1/i) this..That means you use a data directly to assign a "var re" variable..But I want to store a data in one variable and then use this variable to assign a "var re"  variable..It is possible to do????

Comment: @user1800105 - You can statically declare a regular expression as `re = /sample1/i;` or you can dynamically construct one starting with a variable such as `re = new RegExp(str, "i");`.  Either will work.  The latter is useful if the data for the string is in a variable and not known ahead of time.  See the [MDN page on RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Use a regex to test the items in the array and use [$.map](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) to filter the array

```
var s = $.map(samplearray, function(v, i){
    if((/sample/i).test(v)){
        return v;
    }
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/hHFCe/)

Answer (score 0):

If you use jQuery, **grep()** is the proper function:

```
var newArray = $.grep(samplearray, function(n, i) {
    return regex.test(n);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tBBFx/1/

Documentation:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/